# Is Spock Framework available in any public p2 repository?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, osgi, eclipse-rcp, spock, tycho

Is there any public p2 repository where [spock-core-1.1-groovy-2.4.jar](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/spockframework/spock-core/1.1-groovy-2.4/spock-core-1.1-groovy-2.4.jar) and its dependencies would be available? I'd like to include it in my own p2 repository built with Tycho (eclipse-repository packaging), and it turns out it's not straightforward to resolve regular Maven (i.e. non-p2) artifacts in a Tycho build. Spock-core actually already is an OSGi bundle so I guess someone out there probably must have used it in Eclipse environment already...

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know whether `spock-core` can be found in any public p2 repository (your original question), but as it already has an OSGi manifest, you may be able to consume it using `<pomDependencies>consider</pomDependencies>` and a normal Maven `<dependency>` element in your POM. See the Tycho Wiki for [more information on this](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Target_Platform#.22POM_dependencies_consider.22).